# Show variable in blade laravel

Tags: html, laravel

I want to show tags from the database, I have a problem when I wanna display the variable in the blade that is showing me like this.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Splash","slug":"splash","created_at":"2022-07-11T12:00:45.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-07-11T12:00:45.000000Z","listing_id":1,"tag_id":1},{"id":2,"name":"Swimming","slug":"Swimming","created_at":"2022-07-11T12:00:45.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-07-11T12:00:45.000000Z","listing_id":1,"tag_id":1},{"id":3,"name":"Educational","slug":"Educational","created_at":"2022-07-11T12:54:07.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-07-11T12:54:07.000000Z","listing_id":1,"tag_id":1},
```

In controller:

```
public function edit($id,Listing $listing)
    {
        $listing = Listing::findOrFail($id);
        

        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $listing->user_id) {
            $listing = DB::table('listings')
                ->where('id', $id)  
                ->first();

            $tag = Tag::join('listing_tag','listing_id','=','tag_id')
                    ->get();

            return view('listings.edit', compact('listing','tag'));
        } else {
            return (redirect('/dashboard'));
        }
    }
```

View

```
<div class="mx-2 mb-4">
                    <x-label for="tags" value="Tags (separate by comma)" />
                    
                    <x-input
                        id="tags"
                        class="block w-full mt-1"
                        type="text"
                        
                        value=" {{ $tag }} "
                         
                        name="tags" 
                        maxlength="30"/>
                       
                </div>
```

[image]

dd($tag);
[image]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgxKf.png]

Comment: So what is the problem? `A problem` does not describe to us what should happen..

Comment: instead of showing me the whole array, I just want the tag name

Comment: Instead of `value= {{ $tag }}` try `value={{ $tag->name }} `

Comment: You should try `value={{ $tag->name }}` But you get your tags using the `->get()` method, that will cause errors with multiple results

Comment: yes, i get an error: ``` Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\newjoblist\newjoblist\resources\views\listings\edit.blade.php)```

Comment: is there another alternative to get ()?

Comment: If you want 1 result you should use `first()`. If you expect multiple results (tags), you should use `get()`

Comment: If tag is a collection, and you want to show all your tag-names, you can try something like `value={{ $tag->pluck('name')->implode(',')}}`

Comment: @RobBiermann It doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't display anything either.

Comment: You can use `get()` just fine, but then you would have to use a `foreach()` somewhere. @RobBiermann also makes a good point, can you show in your question what `dd($tag)` returns?

Comment: @geertjanknapen with foreach is looking good, but need in value="". After I need it to update the form.

Comment: So you're using a text input seperated by comma. So why not in controller get all tags, append them together with comma's in between each tag and pass that to blade. Then plug that into `value=""` and call it a day?

Comment: @Calvink933 Can you do: `dd($tag->toArray())`. This makes the result more readable.

Comment: @Calvink933 To verify, it should be `value="{{ $tag->pluck('name')->implode(',')}}"` I forgot to include quotes :)